# The default value of the oddsidemargin

Tags: margins, layout

When I use the grid behind the text I see on my first page the distance between the left side of the page and the left margin of the text is around 1.5 inch.

When I use the layout package and the \layout command I see the distance between the left side of the page and the left margin of the text is \oddsidemargin+ one inch+ \hoffset=35pt+1 inch which is around the same measured value 1.5 inch.

So far everything looks fine. But I am surprised why the default value of the oddsidemargin is 18.06749pt on the page 13 of the Layout package instead of 35pt we see as a result of  \layout command below.

The other surprising point is in the \LaTeXe: An Unofficial Reference Manual, page 26, the oddsidemargin is 40% of the difference between the paper width (8.5 inch) and the textwidth (around 4.5 inch) which is 1.6 inch and not 35 pt in the layout package.
Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[grid,
 gridcolor=red!50,
 subgridcolor=green!50,
gridunit=in]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Oddsidemargin}
When I use the grid behind the text I see on my first page the distance between the left side of the 
page and the left margin of the text is around 1.5 inch.

When I use the layout package and the \textbackslash layout command I see the distance between the 
left side of the page and the left margin of the text is \textbackslash oddsidemargin+ one inch+ 
\textbackslash hoffset=35pt+1 inch which is around the same measured value 1.5 inch.

So far everything looks fine. But I am surprised why the default value of the oddsidemargin is 
18.06749pt on the page 13 of the Layout package instead of 35pt we see as a result of  \textbackslash 
layout command below.

The other surprising point is in the \LaTeXe: An Unofficial Reference Manual, page 26, the 
oddsidemargin is 40\% of the difference between the paper width (8.5 inch) and the textwidth (around 
4.5 inch) which is 1.6 inch and not 35 pt in the layout package. 

\layout


\end{document}
```

[image: see picture below]

Comment: So you want to know what the default is? Is that your question?

Comment: Yes what the default is and why we see many contradictions in reporting the default in the references I explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask LaTeX to show you the values.

```
\typeout{  start: \the\oddsidemargin}
\documentclass{book}

\typeout{preamble: \the\oddsidemargin}

\begin{document}

\typeout{  page 1: \the\oddsidemargin}

z
\end{document}
```

produces

```
   start: 0.0pt
preamble: 35.0pt
  page 1: 35.0pt
```

So the default value in the format is 0pt, but as you are using `book` class with the default `usletter`, `10pt`, `onecolumn`  and `twoside` options it gets set to 35pt

You can see the setting in `size10.clo`

It gets set to .4(\paperwidth-\textwidth)-1in = 0.4(614.295pt-345pt)-72.27pt ~ 35.4pt

```
    \setlength\@tempdima        {\paperwidth}
    \addtolength\@tempdima      {-\textwidth}
    \setlength\oddsidemargin    {.4\@tempdima}
    \addtolength\oddsidemargin  {-1in}
```

Then rounded to a whole number of pt = 35pt

```
  \@settopoint\oddsidemargin
```

The actual margin is `\oddsidemargin+1in` so 1+35/72.27 in ~ 1.48in

All of the above is at the default US Letter paper size, if you add `[a4paper]` then `\paperwidth` is different and the final value ends up being 28pt rather than 35pt.

Comment: thank you. Do you know why in the layout package and in the unofficial latex2e manuals they reported different default values I put the page numbers of their reports in my question above.

Comment: @Aria layout package documentation is set in ltxdoc class not book and has a wider left margin (as command names are placed in the margin)

Comment: @Aria I did not understand your page numbers, the diagram in layout.pdf is on page 2 http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/layout.pdf

Comment: @Aria the formula used in book is, as I show above just as you quote 40% of the difference between pagewidth and textwidth minus 1in so that seems right.

Comment: please refer to page 13 of the CTAN Layout package here when they say  the oddsidemargin is 18.06749pt: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf

Comment: the `layout` package is part of the core distribution, with manual at the link I gave. The `layouts` package (with an s) is a completely different alternative contributed  package. Note that the source file of its manual, `layman.tex`  _sets_ the margin `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}`  so it will show that, not the default set by the format.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Now it make sense!